# Why are Newman Projections drawn with 120 degrees when actually sp3 carbons are 109.5 degrees?

Tags: molecular-structure, conformers

Title says the question, pretty much.

For example, in the Newman projection of ethane, the carbon hydrogen bond angles are $120$ degrees, not $109.5$ degrees, as they actually are in an $\text{sp}^3$ hybridized center. Why is this so, and does it have any effect on the arguments traditionally derived from Newman projections?

[image]

Comment: why the downvote? this is a legitimate question

Comment: I also thought to downvote as for is at least bizarre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a projection. Depending on the orientation of a water molecule with respect to the projection plane, the projected angle can be anywhere from zero to 180 degrees. Similarly, the angles in ethane projected to a 2D plane will be different from 109.5 degrees unless the three atoms making up the angle are in the plane:

[image]

Other projections (Fisher projection) make the angles appear as right angles. In either case, the 3D angles remain at 109.5 degrees.